# Is it okay to briefly exceed a resistor's power rating in a high-reliability product?

Tags: power, resistors, reliability

I am dealing with a 0.01R 500mW resistor. It is a current sense resistor and measures the current flowing through a MOSFET and inductor. According to simulations, when the supply starts up, the RMS current is very high (~3A) for about 1 millisecond, and the resistor will be exposed to pulses of ~1.2W. The pulses then drop down to 200mW, and the RMS is around 125mW. Is it okay to briefly exceed the ratings of any resistor?

If I have to pick a 2W resistor it will be much bigger, so I'd like to use a smaller resistor, but reliability is a high priority for this product.

Comment: More important: Do you trust the simulation? Until you actually measure the current pulse, I would assume that it is just the system settling at the beginning of the sim.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The data sheet should mention the peak power or current capabilities of the resistor. It is usually much higher than the mean power rating, but if it is not specified anywhere, I would rather not rely on it.

Note that not all resistors of the same size and power rating are created equal. There are some that are designed (and specified!) for peak power ratings well beyond the mean power rating, and there are some that are not.

I have seen resistors fail when their mean power rating was exceeded just briefly, so it's indeed necessary to check what manufacturer and type you're using and if it has the right specs.

Answer (score 6):

Be careful of film resistors, where the film can be easily vaporized during power surges, EVEN IF the temperature of the entire package remains within safe limits.

Wire wound and resistive pellet resistors have much more thermal inertia than film resistors.

Comment: That comment applies to things like transistors as well.  Some devices have a graph which lists how much current or power may be applied for various lengths of time (e.g. 30 watts for 100us or less; 15 watts for 1ms; 6 watts for 10ms; 3 watts for 100ms, 2 watts for one second, or one watt indefinitely).

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you need to include inrush current limiting in your circuit.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK if you are in I^2T window. This figure is typically applied to motors, not resistors, but still applicable for large resistors. Say if you know that 5W over 10Sec is a limit, then 50W over 1 sec is same limit. But for very small parts with very low thermal mass, its better to use equivalence 10 or 100 times shorter in time. Say 0.5W over 1sec is 5W over 0.1 sec.

So answer is yes. For your example in ms range it is ok if part is heavier than say 0.2..0.5 gram. This kind of parts is designed for precision, so the specs are about staying accurate within working currents. If you exceed the current 10 times for ms you only loose precision, but part is far from being destroyed or self desoldering.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any circuit failures possible that would result in the peak current becoming the steady-state current, then you need to allow for the larger power rating.

Comment: The sense resistor is also used for overcurrent protection, so it would shut down if the output shorted out or hit the current limit.

Comment: Is this a buck converter? If so, a possible failure mechanism is the series switch failing short-circuit, which can lead to downstream damage due to excessive voltage (i.e. a short) and big current through the sense resistor, which may spectacularly fail.

Answer (score 0):

3A through 0.01R is 90mW, not 1.2W. 1.2W would be about 11 amps.

Comment: The RMS current is 3A but the pulse power is 1.2W. It pulses at about 10 amps so that seems right.